# LibTiff.net Not able to update EXIF_USERCOMMENT field

Tags: .net, exif, libtiff.net

I want to simply update the `EXIF_USERCOMMENT` field on a *tif* image I am creating.

The call to `SetField` fails. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my over-simplistic code.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
    Tiff tiffdoc = Tiff.Open("C:\\temp\\~tempCapture.tif","rw");

    bool bSetField = tiffdoc.SetField(TiffTag.EXIF_USERCOMMENT, "test comment field");

    tiffdoc.WriteDirectory();
    tiffdoc.Close();
}
```

Comment: The library writes warnings and errors to console. Could you post them (if any) here?

Comment: SetField: c:\temp\~tempCapture.tif: Unknown tag EXIF_USERCOMMENT

Comment: Appreciate you looking at this. New to EXIF, so I'm probably missing something obvious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like LibTiff.Net can only read EXIF tags and can not write them (original libtiff can't write EXIF tags either).

There is a [discussion in the libtiff mailing list](http://www.asmail.be/msg0054536675.html) about why it is so. Here are some quotes from the discussion:

```
// FIXME -- we don't currently support writing of EXIF fields.  TIFF
// in theory allows it, using a custom IFD directory, but at
// present, it appears that libtiff only supports reading custom
// IFD's, not writing them.
```

Leonard Rosenthol:

```
I don't really think that libTIFF really wants to start down the
metadata "rabbit hole"...
```

Bob Friesenhahn:

```
I do agree with Leonard Rosenthol that libtiff should not be in the 
business of dealing with EXIF private IFD tags (even though it 
somewhat does already).
```

As for the `Unknown tag EXIF_USERCOMMENT`, you should [read an EXIF directory first](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_ReadEXIFDirectory_System_Int64_). The library will add EXIF tags to its list of known tags before reading the EXIF directory and won't issue the error about unknown tags later.

But the library still won't be able to write EXIF tags to file.

**EDIT:**

You have some options in case you only want to store some information in your file and not require it to be stored in the `EXIF_USERCOMMENT` tag.

You can use `IMAGEDESCRIPTION` tag for your task. Below is sample code that uses this tag. Please note that the code uses different params for `Open` method and also uses `RewriteDirectory` instead of `WriteDirectory`.

```
string fileName = "C:\\temp\\~tempCapture.tif";
using (Tiff tiffdoc = Tiff.Open(fileName, "a"))
{
    tiffdoc.SetDirectory(0);
    bool bSetField = tiffdoc.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEDESCRIPTION, "test comment field");
    tiffdoc.RewriteDirectory();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Can you make any recommendations on how to store info to the TIFF file?  I only ended up looking at EXIF because of the "User Comments" section.  I need to store some experimental conditions in the metadata to be available to the end-user.  Thanks for your input and expertise.